# Button on FrameOne shall close FrameTwo. ActionListener referes object of another class in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, frame

I have two frames in separate classes (FrameOne and FrameTwo) FrameOne has two buttons. One to open FrameTwo and One shall close FrameTwo. How to open FrameTwo I know. But not how to close from Frame One. How do I code it to make it working? Thanks. (I know that there are similar questions. I red them all. But it didn't gave me the answer. Also GUI guides didn't helped.)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FrameOne frame = new FrameOne();
    }
}
```

**FrameOne class:**

```
    public class FrameOne extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JButton btn1, btn2;

    FrameOne () {

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400,400);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setTitle("Main");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btn1 = new JButton("opens FrameTwo");
        btn2 = new JButton("close FrameTwo");
        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
        add(btn1);
        add(btn2);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()== btn1) {  
            FrameTow frameTwo = new FrameTwo(); 
        }

        else if(e.getSource()== btn2) ;
        // {???.dispose(); }
    }
}
```

`
**Frame2 class:**

```
    public class FrameTow extends JFrame {

    FrameTwo () {

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400,400);
        setTitle("FrameTwo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocation(400, 400);

    }
}
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: *"Thanks for downvoting me."* Whoever down-voted the question will not be notified of your comment. *"The answer was absolutely helpful and I learned a lot from it."* What answer? Answers are below. I simply made a comment. *"I can not post any answer anymore"* Why not? BTW - did *none* of the current answers solve the problem? You can always accept one by clicking the tick on the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the below solutions will work

```
frameTwo.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frameTwo, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

**OR**

```
frameTwo.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not working because frameTwo cannot be resolved to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is modify `FrameOne` :

```
private JFrame frameTwo; //introduce a field  


@Override
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()== btn1) {
        frameTwo = new FrameTwo();  //use field in action listener 
    }

    else if(e.getSource()== btn2){
        frameTwo.dispose();         //use field in action listener 
    }
}
```

The longer answer: using a `JDialog` for the 2nd frame is a better practice:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       new FrameOne();
    }
}

class FrameOne extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private final JButton btn1, btn2;
    private JDialog frameTwo; //introduce a field

    FrameOne () {

        setSize(400,400);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setTitle("Main");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btn1 = new JButton("opens FrameTwo");
        btn2 = new JButton("close FrameTwo");
        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
        add(btn1);
        add(btn2);
        setVisible(true); //make it visible after construction is completed
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()== btn1) {
            frameTwo = new FrameTwo();  //use field in action listener
        }

        else if(e.getSource()== btn2){
            frameTwo.dispose();         //use field in action listener
        }
    }
}

class FrameTwo extends JDialog {

    FrameTwo() {

        setSize(400,400);
        setTitle("FrameTwo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocation(400, 400);
        setVisible(true); //make it visible after construction is completed
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I havn't had the time to try out today. But I will let you know when I have done. Thank you so far.

Answer (score -1):

In the example you show, one can open several instances of `FrameTwo`. Which one should the second button close?

Assuming you want there to be only one, you could introduce a field in in FrameOne, initially set to `null`. `btn1` would then only open a frame if the field is `null`, and assign it to the field. Then `btn2` can call `dispose()` on the field (and reset it to `null`).

Example, based on your attempt:

```
public class FrameOne extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JButton btn1, btn2;
private FrameTwo frameTwo = null;

FrameOne () {

setVisible(true);
setSize(400,400);
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
setTitle("Main");
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

btn1 = new JButton("opens FrameTwo");
btn2 = new JButton("close FrameTwo");
btn1.addActionListener(this);
btn2.addActionListener(this);
add(btn1);
add(btn2);



}

@Override
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
{if(e.getSource()== btn1) 
{
    if (frameTwo == null) {    
        frameTwo = new FrameTwo();
    }
}

else if(e.getSource()== btn2) {

    frameTwo.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frameTwo, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
    frameTwo = null;

}}}
```

Comment: Like I said; set the field from the btn1 action and use it to close the frame from the btn2 action. If you're stuck with that, please show what you tried.

Comment: can u post a code snipped. I posted an answer. But it is only a field added in the variable declaration. I don't know how to assign the button to the field and so on. I have never worked with a field before.

Comment: @GS I've amended the answer with something based on your attempt.

Comment: Hey Ho. Thank you again. It helps me a lot to understand and to learn how to use JAVA. I do this only for two months and repeating and learning code snippeds by heart is one of my favorite techniques to learn. Since if I know them by heart I come up with questions and start to recognize patterns in other code snippeds. So again thank you a lot. But now the next step is it to make it happen that only FrameTwo is closed by pressing the button because now both are closed when I press the btn2.

Comment: Maybe I can create a method in FrameTwo that states this.dispose();. And then I create an object of FrameTwo that evokes that method by pressing btn2.

Comment: No. It creates just another object that is closed instantly.