# Adding JComponents to JPanel and add the JPanel to JFrame is not working

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame and I want to add a JPanel with a JButton. But all the guides in the internet seem to be wrong. If I follow these instructions my buttons will not be shown.

I know that there are questions similar to mine, but these posts have too much code instead of the problem in an isolated code. So I cannot figure out from it what their solution is.

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
    } 
}

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private JButton btn;
    private JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

    Frame () {
        setSize(400,400);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setButtons();
        add(pnl);
    }

    private void setButtons() {
        btn = new JButton();
        pnl.add(btn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the FlowLayout on the panel (pnl) instead, and set that panel as your content pane (JFrame.setContentPane(pnl)).

Comment: I tried so far now. But it doesn't seem to work. The problem I see is that to address the JFrame by point operator I need to initialize an object of the class (right?). But when I do initialize a JFrame object within the same JFrame object I creat a frame that will open itself endlessly when it is called by the main class.

Comment: In an [answer to a previous question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333096/3992939) you could see: `setVisible(true); //make it visible after construction is completed;`

Answer (score 1):

```
    setVisible(true);
    setButtons();
    add(pnl);
```

Your components have a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

The solution is to make the frame visible AFTER all the components have been added to the frame:

```
    setButtons();
    add(pnl);
    setVisible(true);
```

When you make the frame visible, or use the pack(), method the layout manager is invoked so know the components will have a size/location.

> but these posts have too much code instead of the problem in an isolated code.

I suggest you start with the code example from the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. Download an example and use it as a starting point for a better structured class.  For example all Swing components should be create on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`.